# Hide div overflow using CSS not working with phonegap

Tags: css, cordova

I have a web application and in one of the div's I'm using CSS to show an image over image (using:  `position:relative; top:-100px;`). Due to that I get a white gap in the bottom of the page (of where the second image should have been), so I used `overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: -100px;` in my div, to fix it. It works great when I'm running it in chrome emulation but it does not work when I install the phonegap application on my phone (Nexus 4). 
Is there anything I can do to make it happen with phonegap?

Comment: why not use absolute positioning?

Comment: Thank's for the tip but I really need to use relative positioning here...

Comment: Why dont you try using media queries and position your image.Your position of image will work the same in all the device..You can find many tips on it online,i'll just post a sample link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: use `margin-top` instead of top then - it won't leave the space at the bottom